# When I open modal, nav bar come over the modal?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, opencart

I am working in a open cart framework. Inside that I created a modal page. Thing is that when I open the modal **nav** bar come over it. So how to over come the problem. [click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHmXW.png). I am really stuck at this position. I hope anyone will help me.

Comment: your modal code put on  before complete body tag. because not clear tag

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar has larger `z-index` value than the modal. Just update it to lower value or increase the value of modal.

> The z-index CSS property specifies the z-order of a positioned element and its descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an element with a lower one.

More about `z-index` on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Answer (score 0):

Your nav set it to :

```
top:0px;
position:fixed;
```

And your modal :

```
z-index:2000;
```